# Mathematica is not responding for very large numbers

Tags: programming

So, I am having Mathematica 11.3 and trying to evaluate 2^1,000,000,000.

When I am trying to show the output in its full form to manipulate the digits, Mathematica stops responding.

I am having 32GB of memory so this would not be a problem. Also when I am using Intel's extreme utility to monitor, I find it to always employ 1 kernel out of 8, altho I specifically set it to work with all 8 in the settings and never uses more than 6GB of memory.

Comment: The number 2^1,000,000,000 is not from real life: eg Planck constant^(-1) is 6.626070150(81)*10^34.

Comment: What? It's certainly less than 10^1,000,000,000 and pi has been calculated for trillions of digits.

Comment: @dimachaerus it does not mean you can throw this expansion at any gui and expect it to be responsive.

Comment: Also 2^(10^9) has around 3e8 digits. Are you sure 32GB is enough to interactively play with them?

Comment: For 8 bits= 1 byte a digit, yes I am certain. Also if it ran out of memory it'd show up on the monitor. I am telling you this program never goes further than 6GB of memory and 1 kernel.

Comment: @dimachaerus The number is simply too big to display all at once. It would be equivalent to nearly 54,000 letter-size pages of text and Mathematica has too much overhead to render that quickly. I think the only way forward is to save it to a file and find some program that has no problem rendering 54,000 page documents. You could print it via Unix/Macos command line with the cat command - it worked for me. Windows probably has something similar. Or you could use Wolfram command line to print to the terminal. Sorry I can't be of more help, but I don't think it's possible to do what you want.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "manipulate the digits"?

Comment: @MassDefect Thanks. Of all the answers here, yours is the most relevant. I've come to conclusion that Mathematica can't  handle Notebooks of a certain size upwards: 150 or 200 MB say.

Comment: @dimachaerus You have not answered my question above re. "manipulate the digits". There may be a solution to that question which does not require dealing with a 200MB notebook. [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Answer (score 7):

The Mathematica kernel can handle such numbers. The following returns immediately; note that I suppressed the output with `;`.

```
var = 2^1000000000;
```

The issue you are perhaps experiencing is that the front-end takes a long time to format and print the number.  This is because it is an `Integer`

```
Head@var
```

> ```
> Integer
> ```

and has a large amount of digits

```
IntegerLength@var
```

> ```
> 301029996
> ```

and Mathematica fully prints all digits of integers so this will take the front-end some time. You can return a portion of the digits with `IntegerDigits`; first 10 below.

IntegerDigits[var, 10, 10]

> ```
> {1, 7, 8, 7, 1, 0, 9, 3, 7, 6}
> ```

You can get better print performance using reals instead of integers. The follow returns the print immediately.

```
var2 = 2.^1000000000
```

> ```
> 4.612976001169*10^301029995
> ```

`RealDigits` can be used to return digits in this case.

```
RealDigits[var2, 10, 10]
```

> ```
> {{4, 6, 1, 2, 9, 7, 6, 0, 0, 1}, 301029996}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't help but thanks for the answer. I know all these commands. I am not expecting the  output to be any larger than 100MB in size.

Comment: The output, printed, is characters. This is true whether the number is stringified or just printed as digits. There are a billion bits, so around 300 million base ten digits. At one byte per ascii character (the minimum) this gives 300MB. That factor of three vs stated expectation might or might not be an issue.

Comment: Wrong! It's not 1 byte per character  (digit here), tho I claimed this in a previous comment to make sense for some people who are here for downvoting only. 10^300,000,000=2^1,000,000,000 approx. so it's 1,000,000,000/8 bytes is 125MB approximately, you do the math...but you may be right after all the notebook's size is 300MB after saving it with the full answer.

Comment: Ascii characters, which are what get used in formatting numbers, occupy a whole number of bytes. And I'm perilously close to awarding this one of my quite rare down votes, and voting to close based on the moving target nature of the question. The number itself is 1.25 MB. I'll put the sizes in my actual response, so that the code for computing them is there.

Comment: It seems that a notebook size larger than 150MB is unhandleable by Mathematica. And do what you like with your votes, truth is truth and democracy has nothing to do with it!

Comment: I'm fairly certain truth is not at issue. A really insulting tone is the issue. As for the notebook size, you might be right. Or it might be a problem to mouse inside very large `Box` structures as opposed to raw text (which is why I suggested using `InputForm`). I simply do not know enough about the notebook structure to state anything definitively there. Now arithmetic, I can say a bit about that (like log of 2 base 10 is around a third, that sort of thing).

Comment: Ok, Daniel if I have insulted you in any way, I apologize. You are the last person that I would insult in this thread. @Kuba maybe but not you.

Comment: @dimachaerus any specific reason for this award? :-) p.s. I was not precise, I didn't mean 300MB is more that 32GB but 3e8 digits is quite a long box which undergoes various processes in a FE. Line breaks, syntax highlighting etc etc. Notebook is more than a simple text editor.

Answer (score 2):

[Not a full answer but on the long side for comments.]

It is probably a formatting speed issue. Also note that obtaining the digits in base 10 also takes time (it's an O(n log n) algorithm for n the bit length of the number). One way to see that is as below. Notice that getting digits in base 2 is much faster (it's O(n)).

```
Table[{Timing[IntegerString[2^(10^n)];],
  Timing[IntegerString[2^(10^n), 2];]}, {n, 5, 8}]

(* Out[158]= {{{0., Null}, {0., Null}}, {{0.028, Null}, {0., 
   Null}}, {{0.396, Null}, {0.008, Null}}, {{6.924, Null}, {0.12, 
   Null}}} *)
```

I would expect that `IntegerString` might format faster than printing the digits directly, but I'm too scared to try on my memory-limited machine.

As for sizes: the number will occupy an eight of a gig, since it is exactly a billion bits.

```
ee = 2^(10^9);
ByteCount[ee]

(* Out[14]= 125000080 *)
```

In decimal form, at one byte per character, it will be around 300Mb. This is computed more accurately by any of the means below.

```
Log[10., 2]*10^9

(* Out[20]= 3.01029995664*10^8 *)

Timing[eeString = IntegerString[ee];]
ByteCount[eeString]
StringLength[eeString]

(* Out[21]= {106.264, Null}

Out[22]= 301030064

Out[23]= 301029996 *)
```

Comment: I can run this for `n=9` with 16 GB of RAM.  It takes 98 s on a PC similar in speed to Daniel Lichtblau's.

Comment: That's not what I am asking. To find 2^1,000,000,000 my system takes 0.0468595 s exactly but when I ask Mathematica to show the number in full form: "show all", well  it does show it, but then if I want to copy-paste or move the cursor in the evaluated cell, Mathematica halts forever.

Comment: What are the platform specifics? Is it possible you have a 32 bit front end? Also have you tried putting the result into `InputForm`? This might improve the behavior in terms of manuevering inside the cell.

Comment: No.. Win10 Enterprise x64, 8700k processor. I'll check the InputForm now, might be the answer...

Comment: One possible advantage to the `InputForm` (sort of implicit in a comment by @Kuba) is that it does not have a `BoxData` wrapper. This might translate to an easier time moving a cursor into and through the cell.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau My version of Mathematica with 32GB of RAM goes up to calculate:  "a = TimeObject[Now]; c = 2^480,000,000,000; b = TimeObject[Now]; b - a",  number c not shown of course. Time is 1.29 min. It eats up all memory of my system. For the heck of it I doubled the memory to 64GB. And yes, now I can handle 2^1,000,000,000 easily in any cell form! Question put to rest.

Comment: I'm glad something worked here.